# Azure Dataexplorer ingest CSV ignore trailing columns / variable number of columns

Tags: azure, csv, azure-data-explorer, kql, data-ingestion

I want to ingest csv files from a blob storage container using LightIngest.

The import worked, but then ran into errors because over time we added some more columns to our csv. But we always added them to the end of the line and I don't want to import data from these additional columns. The structure of the first columns hasn't changed.

**The column count can change within a file! So I can't filter the files by name or folder.**

| Format since |  |  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2015 | columnA | columnB | columnC |  |  |
| 2020 | columnA | columnB | columnC | columnD |  |
| 2022 | columnA | columnB | columnC | columnD | columnE |

The mapping is defined like

```json
[
    {
        "Name":"a",
        "DataType":"",
        "Ordinal":"0",
        "ConstValue":null
    },
    {
        "Name":"b",
        "DataType":"",
        "Ordinal":"1",
        "ConstValue":null
    },
    {
        "Name":"c",
        "DataType":"",
        "Ordinal":"2",
        "ConstValue":null
    }
]
```

Command to ingest

```
LightIngest.exe "https://ingest-foo.westeurope.kusto.windows.net/;Fed=True" 
-database:"myDB" -table:"myTable" -source:"https://foobar.blob.core.windows.net/my-container?..." 
-format:"tsv" -pattern:"subfolder/*" -ingestionMappingRef:"my_mapping" -tag:"..."
```

I unfortunately closed the command line after ingestion, so I don't have the exact error message at hand, but it was something like:

> Could not ingest data found 16 columns previous file had 12 columns

How can I ignore additional columns during ingest?